# NativeScript script try to modify Node.JS public directory and failed - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, nativescript, nvm

I try to start Github example from there https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-marketplace-demo and unfortunately failed.
First message I received was "The current application is not compatible with NativeScript CLI 8.5.3. Run 'ns migrate' to migrate your project to the latest NativeScript version."
I made 'ns migrate' and this command complete successfully.

NS script try to modify something in public directory with Node Manager and failed.
If I try to use

```
# npm cache verify
Cache verified and compressed (~\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache)
Content verified: 0 (0 bytes)
Index entries: 1314
Finished in 0.781s
```

However, NativeScript try to sync packages not to NPM or NVM cache, but directly to folder with NVM

```
1349 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\nvm\v18.17.0\node_modules\nativescript-app-sync-cli'
1350 verbose cwd E:\Android\NsGitHubDemo\nativescript-marketplace-demo\node_modules\nativescript-app-sync
1351 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
1352 verbose node v18.17.0
1353 verbose npm  v9.6.7
1354 error code EPERM
1355 error syscall mkdir
1356 error path D:\nvm\v18.17.0\node_modules\nativescript-app-sync-cli
1357 error errno -4048
1358 error [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\nvm\v18.17.0\node_modules\nativescript-app-sync-cli'] {
1358 error   errno: -4048,
1358 error   code: 'EPERM',
1358 error   syscall: 'mkdir',
1358 error   path: 'D:\\nvm\\v18.17.0\\node_modules\\nativescript-app-sync-cli'
1358 error }
1359 error
1359 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
1359 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
1359 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
1359 error
1359 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
1359 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
1359 error the command again as root/Administrator.
1360 verbose exit -4048
```

How to fix this issue? Always working with NativeScript on Computer Administrator account? Or there is normal way?

Any my attempt clear cache was filed "npm cache clean --force" NativeScript still ignored NPM Cache and try to write directly to NVM folder.

Also I try to install various additional packages "npm install nvm-cache --save", but without result, NativeScript still try to write directly to folder witn NVM.

[image: NS ignores Cache and try to write to NVM folder]